# How to solve for m?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve for $m$ in this equation but got stuck here:

$\dfrac{1}{m} = \dfrac{1}{\log{n}} - \dfrac{1}{n}$

This is the original equation:

$(n+m)logn=mn$

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: make a common denominator of the right hand side (which is the product of $n$ and $logn$) and reciprocate the resulting fraction

Comment: Hint: if $y= \frac{1}{x}$, then $x = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}} = \frac{1}{y} $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original equation is
$$
(n + m)\log(n) = mn.
$$
This is a linear equation in $m$, and so you just take all the terms with $m$ to one side
$$
n\log(n) + m\log(n) - mn = 0 \\
m[\log(n) - n] = -n\log(n) \\
m = \frac{...}{...}.
$$

Comment: Very brilliant. Thank you